# Would a spinning magnet generate a current?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

If you were to have a suspended magnet in the shape of an annulus with a wire going through the hole in the center:

- Would rotating the magnet like a wheel (staying in place but spinning) generate a current through the wire?
- If so, what formulas and theorems explain this phenomenon?

Comment: You mean, a current along the length of the wire?  Probably not, but depending on where the poles of the magnet were located, you might generate circular eddy currents _within_ the wire.

Comment: Please specify what the magnetic field is, like how the B-field lines look.

Comment: @SteveByrnes Sorry, I have a really bad professor for my introduction to electromagnetism course right now. It is pretty much "be your own professor" right now. So I have no idea how to specify that to you. Sorry!
But is is essentially a magnet in the shape of a donut with a wire going through the hole, and we are spinning the magnet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes.  Faraday's Law: Whenever the flux linked or associated with a circuit changes, a voltage is induced in the voltage.

$$V_{Ind} = N B l v$$

N = Number of turns.  In your case, N = 1, since it is a straight conductor.

B = flux density in T (Wb/m$^2$).

l = length of coil cutting magnetic field in m.

v - velocity in m/s.

Overall, you get $\mu$V or mV, but it is Faraday's Law.

---

Edit...

[image: Toroidal Magnetic field]

Magnetic field of a Toroid is shown, with a red wire.

No rotation = No voltage.

Rotation but wire is perfectly at center = No voltage.

But if the wire is not perfectly at center, the wire will cut the lines of flux. 
 The magnetic field changes and you will get you get $\mu$V or mV.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but I don't think this is correct. The magnetic field through the center of the annulus would only have a component parallel to the wire, so the flux through the wire isn't changing when the annulus spins.

Comment: does it depend upon the axis of spinning of annulus ?

Comment: The magic Fishy may be correct.  I have no problem with the downvote.  But that assumes the relationship between wire and magnet does not change.  If you keep it in the center, no voltage, but any deviation during rotation would give you some voltage.   Most of the magnetic field would be contained in the annulus, but we are dealing with a 3d magnetic field.

Comment: Interesting... in my class we are creating our own experiments and someone in my group suggested this whole concept and said it was how a magneto, an alternator, and a crank flashlights work. I have been reading relevant sections of various textbooks and have yet to see how. I have also looked at how all three of those work and it does not seem like spinning the magnet is how volts and/or amps are generated.

BUT

He did it! He made it work and I have no idea how it works in the realm of the material from my electromagnetism class.

Comment: Not really.  You can rotate the magnet or the coil.  AC generators rotate the magnet within the coil.  DC generators rotate the coil within the magnetic field.  Here, the magnetic field is inline with wire.  All you are getting would be voltage induced from crossing because of not being in center and dealing with a 3d field.  mV at best.